# mysql Column name change using join

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a table data_table on which i have defined one primary key as d_id and other fields as f1 to f25. 
i have another table as fields_name on which the field name stored as value
f_id, field_name, order

i want to get all data from data table using column name as field_values stored in fields_name table
what i get,

```
f1   f2   f3   f4 
a    b    c    d
```

what i want,

```
field_name1    field_name1    field_name1    field_name1
a              b              c              d
```

Help appriciated.....

Comment: Can you at least try to come up with a possible query for this so people can propose a fix?

Comment: +1 it would really help if you gave us something to work with in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to do something like this:

```
select d_id, 
  max(case when field_name = 'Header' then value end) Header,
  max(case when field_name = 'ID No.' then value end) ID_No,
  max(case when field_name = 'Image' then value end) Image,
  max(case when field_name = 'Name' then value end) Name
from
(
  select d_id, f1 value, 'f1' col
  from data_table
  union all
  select d_id, f2 value, 'f2' col
  from data_table
  union all
  select d_id, f3 value, 'f3' col
  from data_table
  union all
  select d_id, f4 value, 'f4' col
  from data_table
) u
inner join fields_name f
  on u.col = f.a_flag
group by d_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f6cd/5)

Comment: @ManeeshKumar after your comments on the other answer, please see my edit.  It sounds like this it what you are looking for.

Comment: Got error as "#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='"  --  above 2 subqueries are working but i think error is in last join used , tried but not got resolved.  @bluefeet

Comment: thanks @bluefeet error is in collation i fixed that error n all done, thanks for replying

Comment: max(case when field_name = 'Header' then value end) Header

will u plz explain it, i didnt understood what happen under brackets

Comment: @ManeeshKumar what I am doing is swapping the positions, the `CASE` function is saying if the `field_name` is equal to `Header` then use the column `value`.

Answer (score 0):

i dont understand... if you want to rename the column names you can use `AS`

`SELECT f1 AS "field_name1", f2 AS "field_name2", f3 AS "field_name3" FROM table`

EDIT:

try something like this:

`SELECT f1,f2,f3,f4... 
 FROM data_table 
  LEFT JOIN data_table ON data_table.f1=(SELECT field_name FROM fields_names WHERE a_flag='f1') AND data_table.f2=(SELECT field_name FROM fields_names WHERE a_flag='f2')`

Comment: i want to rename columns using join coz i have stored column name as values in another table
i want a table in which user can add columns in table, i have made n column in data_table, which will be accessible when it has a join in field_name table.

Comment: i need to see your table structures then and any queries you already have

Comment: Image: Data Table structure   >>>>
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/mw77k  
Image: Data_table Values  >>>>
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/veuk3
Image: Fields_name Structure and values    >>>>
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/v7fto

Comment: I dont know in this case, I have tried many but nothing worked, [select (select a_flag from fields_name"query to get column name, but since it return multiple rows not worked") from data_table], this is my thought only, not worked. I m not getting how to join table values to column headers, like in the given detail in table data_table column name is like f1, f2, f3....
and in table fields_name as column field_name's value in place of a_flag's corresponding column.@h3rrmiller